# Find the center of mass of a hemispherical shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, volume

Problem: Find the center of mass of a hemispherical shell of constant density and inner radius r1 and outer radius r2.

Attempt at Solution:
Let the hemisphere be in the region $z>0$.
By symmetry, $X_{COM}=0$ and $Y_{COM}=0$ At a height of z, the infinitesimal mass $dm$ can be attributed to a disk of volume with height $dz$, and surface area $\pi a^2-\pi b^2=\pi(a^2-b^2)$, where $a = \sqrt{r_{2}^2-z^2}$ and $b = \sqrt{r_{1}^2-z^2}$ the total volume of the disk at height $z$ is $\pi (a^2-b^2)dz=\pi \Bigg({\bigg[\sqrt{r_{2}^2-z^2}\bigg]}^2 - \bigg[\sqrt{r_{1}^2-z^2})\bigg]^2\Bigg)dz = \pi (r_{2}^2-r_{1}^2)dz$. Mass at height z is $\pi \rho(r_{2}^2-r_{1}^2)dz$. Moment about the XY Plane is $\int_{0}^{r_2}{z\rho\pi (r_{2}^2-r_{1}^2)dz} = \rho\pi (r_{2}^2-r_{1}^2)dz*\frac{r_2^2}{2}$. Divide by the total volume $V = \frac{1}{2}*\rho\frac{4}{3}\pi (r_2^3-r_1^3)$. The center of mass is located at $Z= \frac{3}{4}*\frac{(r_2^2-r_1^2)*r_2^2}{r_2^3-r_1^3}$. However, the official solutions give $\frac{3}{8}*\frac{r_2^4-r_1^4}{r_2^3-r_1^3}$.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please note that [check-my-work questions are off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Comment: Yes,this is off-topic. But as a help to OP i'd suggest reduce problem to a 2D circular arc, which is half of a bagel (torus) with inner radius r1 and outer radius r2. It should have same center of mass by symmetry

Comment: Why a half a torus shape though? Is there anything wrong with using disks instead?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Image_1]

Let us take an elemental shell of thickness $dx$ at a distance of $x$ from the base centre of the hemisphere. So
$$dm=\frac{3M}{2\pi(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.2\pi x^2dx$$ $$=\frac{3M}{(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.x^2dx$$
Now we know that the centre of mass of a hemispherical shell of radius $R$ is $R/2$.
So in order to calculate the centre of mass of the entire hollow hemisphere we need to integrate the equation $$x_{cm}=\frac{\int{x.dm}}{M}$$ with respect to the centre of masses of the elemental shells which will **not** be at a distance $x$ from the base centre, but at a distance of $x/2$ from it. Now the complete equation will look like $$x_{cm}=\frac{1}{M}\int_{R_1}^{R_2}\frac{3M}{(R_2^3-R_1^3)}x^2.\frac{x}{2}dx$$ $$=\frac{3}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}\int_{R_1}^{R_2}{x^3dx}$$ $$=\frac{3}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.\frac{(R_2^4-R_1^4)}{4}$$ $$=\frac{3}{8}\frac{(R_2^4-R_1^4)}{(R_2^3-R_1^3)}$$

[image: Image_2]

Now we can also solve the problem in another way, just the way user63602 did it. The only issue was that the limits that he had taken were from $0$ to $R_2$, but it is important to note that from $R_1$ to $R_2$, we do **not** have an elemental thick ring, rather we have an elemental disc of radius $\sqrt{R_2^2-x^2}$. So we have to find the centre of masses for both regions and add them up.

So for $0<x<R_1$, we will take thick rings as elements.
$$dm=\frac{3M}{2\pi(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.\pi(R_2^2-x^2-R_1^2+x^2)dx$$
$$=\frac{3M}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.(R_2^2-R_1^2)dx$$

So centre of mass for this region, i.e., $0<x<R_1$, is given by
$$x_{CM_1}=\frac{1}{M}.\int_{0}^{R_1}\frac{3M(R_2^2-R_1^2)}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.xdx$$
$$=\frac{3(R_2^2-R_1^2)}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}\int_{0}^{R_1}xdx$$
$$=\frac{3(R_2^2-R_1^2)}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.\frac{R_1^2}{2}$$
$$=\frac{3(R_2^2-R_1^2)R_1^2}{4(R_2^3-R_1^3)}$$

Now for $R_1<x<R_2$, we will take circular discs as elements.
$$dm=\frac{3M}{2\pi(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.\pi(R_2^2-x^2)dx$$
$$=\frac{3M(R_2^2-x^2)}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}dx$$
So the centre of mass for this region, i.e., $R_1<x<R_2$, is given by
$$x_{CM_2}=\frac{1}{M}\int_{R_1}^{R_2}\frac{3M(R_2^2-x^2)}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.xdx$$
$$=\frac{3}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.(R_2^2\int_{R_1}^{R_2}xdx-\int_{R_1}^{R_2}x^3dx)$$
$$=\frac{3}{2(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.[\frac{R_2^2(R_2^2-R_1^2)}{2}-\frac{R_2^4-R_1^4}{4}]$$
$$=\frac{3}{4(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.[R_2^2(R_2^2-R_1^2)-\frac{R_2^4-R_1^4}{2}]$$
So now the centre of mass of the whole body is given by
$$x_{CM_{total}}=x_{CM_1}+x_{CM_2}$$
$$=\frac{3}{4(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.[(R_2^2-R_1^2)R_1^2+R_2^2(R_2^2-R_1^2)-\frac{(R_2^4-R_1^4)}{2}]$$
$$=\frac{3}{4(R_2^3-R_1^3)}.[R_2^2R_1^2-R_1^4+R_2^4-R_1^2R_2^2-(\frac{(R_2^4-R_1^4)}{2})]$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}\frac{(R_2^4-R_1^4)}{(R_2^3-R_1^3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

As you said $y_{cm}=x_{cm}=0$ by symmetry, now

$$z_{cm}=\frac{\int \rho z dV}{\int \rho dV}=\frac{\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \rho z r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi  }{\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \rho r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi}. $$

Next recall in the spherical ccordinates $z=r\cos\theta$, integrate to get
$$z_{cm}=\frac{3}{8}\frac{r_2^4-r_1^4}{r_2^3-r_1^3}. $$